# Getting weird errors when running node index.js w/npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Okay so I was trying to make a discord bot following a tutorial when I noticed some weird errors.

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('JokeBot is online!')
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot ) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
});

client.login(YOUR_TOKEN);
```

And these are the errors:

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
    '/media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
    '/media/oli/MID/Projects/JS/Bot/index.js'
  ]
}
```

May I remind you that running `npm install` on those packages didn't work and just returned a lot of npm errors.
I don't know what to do
Edit:

It's still saying that even when I updated node.js

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: Upgrade your Node version to 16.6+

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is happening because you are using nodejs less than version `16.6.0`. `discord.js` requires node.js version more than or equal to `16.6.0`. Try running `node -v` command in your terminal and that might be less than `16.6.0` then download and install that version of node.

Also add this in your `package.json`

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16.6.0"
}
```

Also, in your code, you misspelled `length`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in order to use `discord.js`. So You just need to update `nodejs` to `v16.6.` And Your error will be solved.